# HTMl , CSS Background image opacity isn't working

Tags: html, css, background, opacity

This is the code the opacity isn't working help please.

```
<html>
<style>
body {
   z-index: -1;
   opacity: 20%;
}
</style>
<body>
<body class="my-container" style="background-image: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3KNQfA21QyQ/maxresdefault.jpg');">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set opacity in range: 0 to 1, for eg. 0; 0.1; 0.2 .... 0.9; 1.

Comment: still didnt work

my-container {
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.1;
}

<body class="my-container" style="background-image: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3KNQfA21QyQ/maxresdefault.jpg');">

Answer (score 0):

Opacity doesn't work on the body element.

Add a `<div>` child and use whatever you were using for the body inside that div. Instant fix.